# Relationships between irrational numbers

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi, euler-mascheroni-constant

Euler’s formula relates $e$ and $\pi$ (also $0$, $1$ and $i$).  Are there relationships between other irrational numbers? Indeed, are there families of related irrational numbers?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You might want to exclude unremarkable relationships like $0 - \sqrt2=-\sqrt2$